# Which spells do winners most often learn?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

In Dungeon Crawl Stone Soup — in the early game, the midgame, and the endgame — which spells are most often memorized by winners?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what use this is; if the spells you gain are random, then knowing which spells the winners use doesn't help you at all.

Comment: @fbueckert:  Once you've found a lot of spellbooks, [the wiki article](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Spell_popularity) and [the raw statistics](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eKhhjemn) can help you decide which spells from your spellbooks to learn first.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many spells you can learn?  That's about the only use I can see of this question; so you know which spells to prioritize.  If you can learn anything and everything, with no limit, then there's no point to this question, from what I can see.

Comment: @fbueckert: Yes: there is indeed a limit. Have you ever played Crawl, even once? If not, why question my question? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ["Spell popularity"](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Spell_popularity) article on CrawlWiki, as well as <https://loom.shalott.org/learndb.html#good_spells>, contain some of the answers. This post is based mainly on those sources.

- In the early to mid-game: Mephitic Cloud. You can also use Passwall to escape monsters through 1-thickness walls.
- All game long: Blink, Apportation, Swiftness, Repel Missiles, Regeneration, Animate Skeleton, Summon Butterflies, and Flight.
- As soon as you can cast them reliably: Control Teleport and Haste.

See the aforementioned wiki article: it includes much more information. This includes information on direct-damage spells, plus a link to the raw endgame spell-popularity statistics.

<sub>This post is up-to-date for Crawl 0.14. Please edit the wiki article and this post, and add to them. If you'd like me to mark this answer as community-wiki, please comment and request it.</sub>